# Can you read variable data of an already running Python Script from its DMP file in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, save

I have a Python program that had some kind of error that prevents it from saving my data. The program is still running, but I cannot save anything. Unfortunately, I really need to save this data and there seems to be no other way to access it.

Does the DMP file created for the process through the task manager contain the data my program collected, and if so, how do I access it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it contain some or all of the current execution state of your program?  Yes.  Is it in a form that you could easily extract the information in the user-level format you are probably looking for from it?  Probably not.  It will dump the state of the entire Python interpreter, including the data as represented in memory for the specific Python program that is running.  To reconstruct that data, I'm pretty sure you'd need to run the Python interpreter itself in debug mode, then try to reconstruct your data from whatever your C debugger can piece together.  If this sounds very difficult or impossible to you, then you probably have some understanding of what it entails.

Comment: Ok. I figured it was a long shot. Thanks for the answer.